# How to expand a large dataframe in R

Tags: r, plyr, expand, reshape, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4), 
  date = c("1985-06-19", "1985-06-19", "1985-06-19", "1985-08-01", 
           "1985-08-01", "1990-06-19", "1990-06-19", "1990-06-19", 
           "1990-06-19", "2000-05-12"), 
  spp = c("a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b"),
  y = rpois(10, 5))

   id       date spp y
1   1 1985-06-19   a 6
2   1 1985-06-19   b 3
3   1 1985-06-19   c 7
4   2 1985-08-01   c 7
5   2 1985-08-01   d 6
6   3 1990-06-19   b 5
7   3 1990-06-19   c 4
8   3 1990-06-19   d 4
9   3 1990-06-19   a 6
10  4 2000-05-12   b 6
```

I want to expand it so that there is every combination of id and spp and have `y = 0` for every combination that is not currently in the dataframe. The dataframe is currently about 100,000 rows and 15 columns. When expanded it would be about 300,000 columns (there are 17 unique values of `spp` in my actual dataset).

For every value of `id` the `date` is the same (e.g. when id = 2, date always = 1985-08-01). In my real dataset all the columns except `spp` and `y` can be specified by the `id`.

I want to end up with something like:

```
   id       date spp y
   1 1985-06-19   a 6
   1 1985-06-19   b 3
   1 1985-06-19   c 7
   1 1985-06-19   d 0*
   2 1985-08-01   a 0*
   2 1985-08-01   b 0*
   2 1985-08-01   c 7
   2 1985-08-01   d 6
   3 1990-06-19   b 5
   3 1990-06-19   c 4
   3 1990-06-19   d 4
   3 1990-06-19   a 6
   4 2000-05-12   a 0*
   4 2000-05-12   b 6
   4 2000-05-12   c 0*
   4 2000-05-12   d 0*
```

- Indicate added rows

I will likely have to do this in the future with potentially much larger data frames, so a quick, efficient (time and memory) way to do this would be appreciated but any solution would satisfy me. I figure there should be ways to use the `dplyr`, `data.table`, or `reshape` packages but I'm not very familiar with any of them. I'm not sure if it would be easiest to expand just rows id, spp, and y, then do a `left_join()` or `merge()` to recombine date (and all the other variables in my real dataframe) based on `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`expand.grid` is a useful function here,

```
mergedData <- merge(
    expand.grid(id = unique(df$id), spp = unique(df$spp)),
    df, by = c("id", "spp"), all =T)

mergedData[is.na(mergedData$y), ]$y <- 0

mergedData$date <- rep(levels(df$date),
                       each = length(levels(df$spp)))
```

Since you're not actually doing anything to subsets of the data I don't think `plyr` will help, maybe more efficient ways with `data.table`.

Answer (score 2):

I would go the second way, hope this helps

```
x<-unique(df$id)
y<-unique(df$spp)
newdf<-data.frame(x=rep(x,each=length(y)),y=rep(y, length(x)))
merged<-merge(newdf, df, by.x=c(x,y), by.y=c("id","spp"), all=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a new function `complete` in the development version of `tidyr` that does this. Of course `complete` uses `expand.grid` internally.

```
# get new version of tidyr
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
# load package
require(tidyr)
# calculations
complete(df, c(id, date), spp, fill = list(y = 0))
##    id       date spp y
## 1   1 1985-06-19   a 5
## 2   1 1985-06-19   b 3
## 3   1 1985-06-19   c 5
## 4   1 1985-06-19   d 0
## 5   2 1985-08-01   a 0
## 6   2 1985-08-01   b 0
## 7   2 1985-08-01   c 4
## 8   2 1985-08-01   d 9
## 9   3 1990-06-19   a 8
## 10  3 1990-06-19   b 3
## 11  3 1990-06-19   c 5
## 12  3 1990-06-19   d 6
## 13  4 2000-05-12   a 0
## 14  4 2000-05-12   b 3
## 15  4 2000-05-12   c 0
## 16  4 2000-05-12   d 0
```