# adding default values to item x group pairs that don't have a value (df %>% spread %>% gather seems strange)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

## Short version

How to do the operation

```
df1 %>% spread(groupid, value, fill = 0) %>% gather(groupid, value, one, two)
```

in a more natural way?

## Long version

Given a data frame

```
df1 <- data.frame(groupid = c("one","one","one","two","two","two", "one"),
                  value = c(3,2,1,2,3,1,22),
                  itemid = c(1:6, 6))
```

for many itemid and groupid pairs we have a value, for some itemids
there are groupids where there is no value.  I want to add a default
value for those cases.  E.g. for the itemid 1 and groupid "two" there
is no value, I want to add a row where this gets a default value.

The following tidyr code achieves this, but it feels like a strange
way to do it (the default value added here is 0).

```
df1 %>% spread(groupid, value, fill = 0) %>% gather(groupid, value, one, two)
```

I am looking for suggestions on how to do this in a more natural way.

Since in some weeks looking at the above code I would likely be confused
about its effect I wrote a function wrapping it:

```
#' Add default values for missing groups
#' 
#' Given data about items where each item is identified by an id, and every
#' item can have a value in every group; add a default value for all groups
#' where an item doesn't have a value yet.
add_default_value <- function(data, id, group, value, default) {
  id = as.character(substitute(id))
  group = as.character(substitute(group))
  value = as.character(substitute(value))
  groups <- unique(as.character(data[[group]]))

  # spread checks that the columns outside of group and value uniquely
  # determine the row.  Here we check that that already is the case within
  # each group using only id.  I.e. there is no repeated (id, group).
  id_group_cts <- data %>% group_by_(id, group) %>% do(data.frame(.ct = nrow(.)))
  if (any(id_group_cts$.ct > 1)) {
    badline <- id_group_cts %>% filter(.ct > 1) %>% top_n(1, .ct)
    stop("There is at least one (", id, ", ", group, ")",
         " combination with two members: (",
         as.character(badline[[id]]), ", ", as.character(badline[[group]]), ")")
  }

  gather_(spread_(data, group, value, fill = default), group, value, groups)
}
```

Last note: reason for wanting this is, my groups are ordered (week1, week2, ...)
and I am looking to have every id have a value in every group so that after
sorting the groups per id I can use cumsum to get a weekly running total that
is also shown in the weeks where the running total didn't increase.

Comment: You could use `left_join` with `expand.grid` and then replace NA with 0.  I don't know whether that would be more natural than the `spread/gather` approach `left_join(expand.grid(groupid=unique(df1$groupid), itemid=unique(df1$itemid)), df1)` or `library(data.table); setkey(setDT(df1), groupid, itemid)[CJ(groupid=unique(groupid), itemid=unique(itemid))][is.na(value), value:=0][]`

Comment: `expand.grid` was also the solution suggested in this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059308/how-to-expand-a-large-dataframe-in-r)

Comment: This question seems fairly similar to [a question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451372/add-rows-to-grouped-data-with-dplyr) some time ago. The best answer there was to use `xtabs` - for this example: `df1 %>% xtabs(formula = value ~ itemid + groupid) %>% data.frame` would work, or without pipes: `as.data.frame(xtabs(value ~ itemid + groupid, data = df1))`

Comment: xtabs looks good for this. I'll have to think a little more, but it almost looks like my question is about an implementation of xtabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new function `complete` in the development version of `tidyr` that does this.

```
df1 %>% complete(itemid, groupid, fill = list(value = 0))
##    itemid groupid value
## 1       1     one     3
## 2       1     two     0
## 3       2     one     2
## 4       2     two     0
## 5       3     one     1
## 6       3     two     0
## 7       4     one     0
## 8       4     two     2
## 9       5     one     0
## 10      5     two     3
## 11      6     one    22
## 12      6     two     1
```

Comment: Use `devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")` to get the development version of `tidyr`.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `expand` from `tidyr`. This approach is very similar to the `expand.grid` idea of @akrun (it actually uses `expand.grid` internally). I used the `dplyr` package for the housekeeping after joining the expanded data with the original data.

This approach is longer than the `spread/gather` approach. Personally I find it a bit more clear what is going on. In my (rather small) benchmark test, `spread/gather` performed slightly better than `expand/join`.

```
# expand first
expand(df1, itemid, groupid) %>% 
  # then join back to data
  left_join(df1, by = c("itemid", "groupid")) %>%
  # because there is no fill argument in join
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), 0, value)) %>%
  # rearange
  arrange(groupid, itemid)
```

Comment: I did not know about expand, thanks.  Unfortunately the expand, left_join, mutate combination still needs a wrapper in a function (like e.g. add_default_value in the question) to be comprehensible to me in a week or two.